# configure apache for SVN SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, svn, mod-dav-svn

I have an issue with my Apache config, specifically how it interacts with the SVN DAV mod.

What I want to be able to do is have `domain.com` point at my website, `svn.domain.com` to point at my svn directory (which is currently outside of my public_html directory) and for both to be accessible via https.

I've got it working for the most part, but if I set up an explicit VirtualHost for the `svn` subdomain, it stops the svn application from being able to access the repositories (instead just getting a "repository moved permanently" error), I can browse the repos ok.

my config looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com svn.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/website/dir
    ...
    #stuff for SSL cert etc.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/website/dir
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<Location /repo>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /path/to/repos
    ... #auth details
</Location>
```

This works mostly, but browsing to `svn.domain.com` brings up my website, and browsing to `domain.com/repo` brings up the repository (`svn.domain.com/repo` works fine, `domain.com` also works fine), potentially I'd maybe want `domain.com/repo` to display a set of webpages all about my project, docs etc, `svn.domain.com` would ideally point to either nothing, or a list of the repositories available or a separate page or something. I thought I'd got the hang of apache config files, but this one is stumping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a separate `<VirtualHost>` directive for your `svn.domain.com` and `domain.com / www.domain.com` domains. It looks like you're trying to squeeze both in to the first `<VirtualHost>`. After you have them separated, put the SVN directives inside the `svn.domain.com` host.

Comment: I tried this at first but when `svn.domain.com` has its own virtual host, running the `svn` command on remote boxes fails, complaining that it has "moved permanently" and can't interact with the repository at all. Browsing the repository via a web browser works fine though! The error I get is `svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.domain.com/repos/'; please relocate`

Comment: Got it! I had another go at splitting it out, this time leaving out the `DocumentRoot` directive from the svn virtualhost, figuring that I don't actually want apache trying to serve any documents, SVN needs to do it. Everything works as I want, with the single exception that I can't get `svn.domain.com` to display a webpage, I just get Forbidden, `svn.domain.com/repos` displays the repos fine, `domain.com/repo` give me the 404 error I expect. Thank you

Comment: That's probably because the checkout you have still points to the old http:// address. You need to use `svn switch --relocate` on your working copy to update the address.

Comment: I had been getting the error even when doing an `svn info https://svn.domain.com/repos`, I have the repos accessible via both http and https at the moment